# Java Eclipse linked projects

Tags: java, eclipse, project

If I for project1 put on build path project2 - project2 will be build before project1?
So classes from project2 can be referenced in project1?
But what will be in case when also project2 uses classes from project1?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not create circular references (project1 references project2 and project2 references project1).

If each of your project represent a "layer" for your application (for example, presentation layer, and business layer), only one layer must know the other (in this example, only presentation layer knows about business layer and calls it).

If each project needs other project utility classes, just extract those classes into a third project, and make each project reference this third project.

A third solution is to merge your 2 projects.